# how to map keys to columns and values to rows in python accoridng to grafana json format dynamically

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, grafana

I want to parse keys as columns and values as rows according to the below grafana json format dynamicaly picking keys as columns and values as rows in python.  Is there any method or library like lambda or any???help me out guys.

```
  mydata = [{"one":"1","two":"2"},
            {"one":"3","two":"4"}]


Grafana expected json format structure for converting json to table format:
  [
 {
   "columns":[
   {"text":"Time","type":"time"},
  {"text":"Country","type":"string"},
  {"text":"Number","type":"number"}
],
"rows":[
  [1234567,"SE",123],
  [1234567,"DE",231],
  [1234567,"US",321]
],
"type":"table"
 }
]
```

*How to convert grafana way of columns to my keys and my values to grafana way of rows in python dynamically. is there any lambda or any script  in python for this??please help me out guys i tried in many different ways couldnt figured it out

Comment: Your `mydata` doesn't match grafana. Show us the expected output.

Comment: Could you also give us an example of the data you're trying to convert, as Tom said your `mydata` doesn't match up. Also, would you include the python code that you've already tried, it will give us a better idea of what you're trying to achieve. And as you're new, welcome :), have a read of these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask